# How can I pick one of two image sizes using CSS functions, not media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following CSS, which produces a side-scrolling gallery of images that fits one image to screen width at viewports of up to 500px, and two above that. How can I rewrite it to use CSS functions instead of media queries? I've looked at MDN's documentation for [`min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max()), [`max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()), and [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()) and it's really confusing how to do anything beyond the specified examples, which themselves are confusing. ("Think of the `min()` value as providing the maximum value a property can have.")

```css
@media (min-width: 501px) {
  img { width: 48vw; }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  img { width: 96vw; }
}

body { margin: 0; }

ul {
  margin: 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

ul {
  margin: 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  width:clamp(48vw,calc(100vw - 500px)*-999,96vw);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
</ul>
```

For more detail, check my article: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/ where you will find a lot of tricks without media query including the above one

You can also do like below:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

ul {
  margin: 2vw;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-auto-columns: clamp(50%,calc(100vw - 500px)*-999,100%);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
  <li><img src=http://placekitten.com/1280/960>
</ul>
```